# React-hook-form: recursively inject props to nested custom fields

Tags: reactjs, forms, recursion, react-hook-form

I want to set up a custom `Form` component using react-hook-form that can handle fields that are potentially nested or wrapped in other elements. My approach is to go through the component tree and recursively pass `register` and `errors` (returned by useForm()) to all leaf nodes that are input fields.

For example, a simple sign-up form. The first and last name fields are wrapped in a div that styles them to be on the same line. The form looks like this:

```
      <Form
        onSubmit={onSubmit}
        styles={["login_form"]}
        showButton
        buttonText='SIGN UP'>

        // These are the wrapped fields
        <div className='signup_name_field'>
          <TextInput name={"fname"} label={"first"} />
          <TextInput name={"lname"} label={"last"} />
        </div>

        <TextInput name={"email"} label={"email"} />
        <TextInput password={true} name={"password"} label={"password"} />
        <TextInput
          password={true}
          name={"passwordConfirm"}
          label={"confirm password"}
        />
      </Form>
```

I created a custom Form component following react-hook-form's example but added a recursive function to handle nested or wrapped fields:

```
  const recursiveInjectProps: any = (children: any) => {
    return React.Children.map(children, (child) => {
      if (child.props.children) {
        recursiveInjectProps(child.props.children);
        return child;
      } else {
        if (child.props.name) {
          return React.createElement(child.type, {
            ...{
              ...child.props,
              register: register,
              key: child.props.name,
            },
          });
        } else {
          return child;
        }
      }
    });
  };

  return (
    <form className={styles.join(" ")} onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      {recursiveInjectProps(children)}
      {renderButton()}
    </form>
  );
```

And TextInput looks like this:

```
  const checkRegister = () => {
    if (register) {
      return (
        <div className='login_field'>
          <input
            className='login_input'
            name={name}
            placeholder={label}
            ref={register(validation)}
            type={password ? "password" : "text"}
            {...rest}
          />
          <label htmlFor={name} className='login_label' />
          {errors && errors[name] && errors[name].message}
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return <div>no dice</div>;
    }
  };
  return checkRegister();
```

The issue is that `recursiveInjectProps()` is failing to inject `register` and `errors` for children that are more than one layer deep (so, the name fields that are wrapped in the div).
I know this because when it renders I see "no dice" where the name fields should be.

Would really appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you should use context API: https://react-hook-form.com/api#useFormContext

```
import React from "react";
import { useForm, FormProvider, useFormContext } from "react-hook-form";

export default function App() {
  const methods = useForm();
  const onSubmit = data => console.log(data);

  return (
    <FormProvider {...methods} > // pass all methods into the context
      <form onSubmit={methods.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <NestedInput />
        <input type="submit" />
      </form>
    </FormProvider>
  );
}

function NestedInput() {
  const { register } = useFormContext(); // retrieve all hook methods
  return <input name="test" ref={register} />;
}
```

Comment: That is a much better solution, thank you!